# Strange behavior when replicating elements of a vector in R

Tags: r

I have the following code.

```
interleave <- function(v1, v2)
{
    ord1 <- 2*(1:length(v1))-1
    ord2 <- 2*(1:length(v2))
    c(v1,v2)[order(c(ord1,ord2))]
}
widths = c(83, 17, 85, 15, 77, 23, 75, 25, 71, 29, 68, 32, 64, 36, 60, 
           40, 57, 43, 54, 46, 42, 58)
rep(interleave(1:11,22:12)[i],times=widths[i])

mat.contents=unlist(sapply(1:22,function(i) rep(interleave(1:11,22:12)[i],times=widths[i])))

> table(mat.contents)
1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 
83 85 77 75 71 68 64 60 56 54 42 57 46 43 40 36 32 28 25 23 15 17
```

Where `5` is replicated 71 times but `18` which is the other digit in the 5 and 18 pair is only replicated 28 times and 71 + 28 =/= 100, which it should since as you can see in `widths`, 71 and 29 are adjacent to eachother.

Can this behavior be corrected?

For clarity, the pairs in unlisted vector format should be:

```
> 1 22  2 21  3 20  4 19  5 18  6 17  7 16  8 15  9 14 10 13 11 12
```

And the corresponding widths:

```
> 83 17 85 15 77 23 75 25 71 29 68 32 64 36 60 40 57 43 54 46 42 58
```

Comment: I forgot to put the code to initialize `widths`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
v1 <- interleave(1:11, 22:12)
table(rep(factor(v1, levels=unique(v1)), widths))
# 1 22  2 21  3 20  4 19  5 18  6 17  7 16  8 15  9 14 10 13 11 12 
#83 17 85 15 77 23 75 25 71 29 68 32 64 36 60 40 57 43 54 46 42 58
```

Comment: @Brad Sorry, I didn't understand.  You showed the expected vector format and corresponding widths, which seems to be the same as the one I showed

Comment: When I use the code provided in your answer, I still get: 5 being replicated 71 times (as it should) but 18 being replicated 28 times (but it should be 29). I don't get the output you've provided above for some reason

Comment: @Brad I get 29 for 18 if that is what you mentioned.  I am using `R 3.1.2`. Which version of R you have?

Comment: R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10). Ok, that was very strange. The problem is that the `widths` vector I've defined was not hard-coded as above and I think it was to do with some kind of rounding up error. Anyway thanks.